# Error when using a precompiled Azure Function with extra methods

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a very simple Precompiled function (copied code from tool generated):

```
public class Foo
    {
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req)
        {
            //log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            // Set name to query string or body data
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
```

The dll this resides in is copied to the Function's folder and is linked up in function.json like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "ExternalFunction.dll",
  "entryPoint": "ExternalFunction.Foo.Run",  
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

This all works fine.

What I then wanted to do was add a private method to be called from the Run method, so (baby steps) I added this to the Foo class:

```
private static string Test()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

This results in these errors in the CLI tools:

> error AF007: A method matching the entry point name provided in
>   configuration ('ExternalFunction.Foo.Run') does not exist. Your
>   function must contain a single public method, a public method named
>   'Run', or a public method matching the name specified in the
>   'entryPoint' metadata property. Function compilation error error
>   AF007: A method matching the entry point name provided in
>   configuration ('ExternalFunction.Foo.Run') does not exist. Your
>   function must contain a single public method, a public method named
>   'Run', or a public method matching the name specified in the
>   'entryPoint' metadata property.

Which is a very odd message as surely adding the private static method should have no effect on Functions being able to find the public method specified in function.json?!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed odd.

I'll work on a repro and open an issue to address the problem if this turns out to be a defect (I'll update the issue or the results of my investigation), but in the meantime, you should be able to create those methods in a different class (static or otherwise) and call that method on that class.

Comment: This was indeed a bug and I'm just wrapping up some tests to open a PR with the fix. Thanks for reporting!
In the meantime, the above workaround should work for you, but let me know if you continue to have problems.